Should I provide more information to an answered post?
I asked this question and have gotten an answer. However, it seems that I somehow wrote my inference quite incorrect to my thinking, so the answer might consider wrong about my understanding about the problem. Should I edit the post? I do worry that the answerer must take his time to edit his answer. Or, I need to ask a new question about the problem, don't I?

I don't understand what you are asking.  I don't know what "wrote my inference quite incorrect" means.  If you edit your post, will it invalidate the existing answer?

By the way, I think it might be a mistake to ask "Why doesn't X?" when you don't know whether X is true or false.  I think it might be better to ask whether X is true or not.

@D.W. Thank you your recommend. Fortunately, the author also has updated his answer. I'll edit the title as your suggestion.
